# Missing number treated as zero error when using titlesec package and tableofcontents

Tags: latex

Whenever I use the package titlesec and later the command \tableofcontents I get the following error:

I created the following MRE below

```
! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>}\tableofcontents
```

In the past this never happened, but since I installed MikTex on my new laptop, those lines below do not work anymore.

Removing the package titlesec seems to work, but I would rather know the actual reason for this problem.

```latex
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[
    %draft, 
    pdftex,
    paper=a4,
    %paper=portait,     % Paper Setting
    pagesize=auto,
    fontsize=11pt,      % Font Size
    version=last,           % Version
    %headsepline,           % Line after header
     %footsepline,          % Line before footer   
]{scrartcl}

\KOMAoptions{parskip=true}

% Depth of content table
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would not use titlesec together with a koma script document class. Koma has its own means to customise the toc. If you want to load the titlesec package to set the depth of the toc, simply use something like `\setcounter{tocdepth}{\sectiontocdepth}` instead